# Reemplazar texto con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero reemplazar el texto *Like* del elemento auxiliar del botón de *Me gusta*, como se ve en la imagen siguiente:

[image]

Al mantener el cursor sobre la opción de *Like* en Twitter, se crea un elemento nuevo dentro de `#layers`.

He probado con el siguiente *snippet*:

```js
$('#layers div[role=tooltip] span span').text('foo');
```

pero al hacerle *hover* se produce un bucle infinito (?) y la pestaña deja de responder.

También he probado con `MutationObserver` junto al *snippet* de arriba pero me devuelve el mismo bucle. Incluso si lo meto dentro de un `console.log()`, la consola empieza a soltar una burrada de logs, lo que vuelve a dejar pillada la pestaña.

El único *snippet* que actualmente me funciona es el que sigue:

```js
$(function() {
 window.setInterval(function() {
  $('#layers div[role=tooltip] span span').text('foo');
 }, 0);
});
```

pero se nota un *glitch* o cambio rápido de *Like* a *foo*, lo que no genera una buena experiencia de usuario.

**Nota:** la palabra *Like* debe reemplazarse en todos los tweets, no solo en el primer elemento.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar usando la función replace de jQuery y activar la función al cargar el sitio usando Document Ready

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#layers").hover(function(){ // Activamos la función al hacer hover
  var replaced = jQuery("#layers").html().replace('Like','Me gusta'); // Obtenemos el texto a cambiar
    jQuery("#layers").html(replaced); // Cambiamos el texto
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layers">
  <div role="tooltip">
    <span>Like</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: En realidad, la función `replace` NO es de jQuery, el método `.html()` te da un string, el cual tiene métodos predefinidos de Javascript, uno de ellos es [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace); +1

Comment: No funciona. El elemento [role=tooltip] existe solamente cuando se hace *hover* en el botón. Al tratar de aplicar el código, me vuelve a dar un bucle y la pestaña se queda colgada.

Comment: @ortiz prueba usando .hover() revisa mi respuesta de nuevo

Comment: Usando tu código en Twitter, no funciona. También probé con ```.hover()``` y nada. Le remito a probarlo su propio código en Twitter para ver que tampoco va.

Comment: Lo estas probando directamente en la pagina de twitter.com o estar usando alguna API de twitter en tu sitio

Comment: Un addon de Firefox pero vamos, el ```script.js``` está vacío.